# [Javascript]: Merge two arrays of object that has string & array values

Tags: javascript

```
const FirstData = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    data: ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    data: ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4', 'hello5'],
  },
];
```

SecondData's data is shuffled behind the scene

```
const SecondData = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    data: ['foo3', 'foo1', 'foo2'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    data: ['b', 'c', 'a'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    data: ['hello1', 'hello3', 'hello2'],
  },
];
```

***EXPECTED OUTPUT* (Must be similar to SecondData but the new strings from FirstData's data must be pushed, added or merged):**

```
[
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    data: ['foo3', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo4', 'foo5'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    data: ['b', 'c', 'a'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    data: ['hello1', 'hello3', 'hello2', 'hello4', 'hello5'],
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you add what you've attempted? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest concatenating the arrays, then using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the values by `title`.

For each entry, we merge the data array using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which will discard any duplicate values in this array.

```js
const FirstData = [ { title: 'Title 1', data: ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5'], }, { title: 'Title 2', data: ['a', 'b', 'c'], }, { title: 'Title 3', data: ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4', 'hello5'], }, ];

const SecondData = [ { title: 'Title 1', data: ['foo3', 'foo1', 'foo2'], }, { title: 'Title 2', data: ['b', 'c', 'a'], }, { title: 'Title 3', data: ['hello1', 'hello3', 'hello2'], }, ];

// Concatenate our data to get input...    
const input = FirstData.concat(SecondData);

// Group each item by title. 
// For each item, merge the data array using a Set object
const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, { title, data }) => { 
    acc[title] = acc[title] || { title, data: [] };
    acc[title].data = [...new Set([...acc[title].data, ...data])];
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a map that indexes based on title and then use `Set` to make sure that you don't add duplicates. Something like this:

```
const items = {}

firstData.forEach(item => {
 items[item.title] = new Set([...item.data)]
})

secondData.forEach(item => {
 const existingItem = items[item.title]

 if(!existingItem) {
  items[item.title] = new Set([...item.data)]
 } else {
  items[item.title] = new Set([...existingItem, ...item.data])
 }
})

const merged = Object.keys(items).map(title => ({
  title: key,
  data: [...items[key]]
 })
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer I'm looking for. The first foreach must be secondData and second foreach must be firstData to get the expected output. Thank you!!!! ❤️❤️❤️

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the given array from random values.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => [
        ...a,
        ...b.filter((s => v => !s.has(v))(new Set(a)))
    ],
    given = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5'],
    random = ['foo3', 'foo1', 'foo2'],
    result = merge(random, given);

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looked like the simplest solution to me. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

```
const FirstData = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    data: ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    data: ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4', 'hello5'],
  },
];

const SecondData = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    data: ['foo3', 'foo1', 'foo2'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    data: ['b', 'c', 'a'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    data: ['hello1', 'hello3', 'hello2'],
  },
];


let newArr = Array.from(FirstData)
for(let i  = 0; i < FirstData.length; i++) {
    let data = new Set([...SecondData[i].data, ...newArr[i].data])
  newArr[i].data = Array.from(data)
}
console.log(newArr)
```